# MediaCodec Encoding camera surface presentationTime not uniform

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I am encoding raw video (1080p) from the camera preview using the MediaCodec class in asynchronous mode. I read the presentation time using the *MediaCodec.BufferInfo.presentationTimeUs* parameter.

```
void onOutputBufferAvailable (MediaCodec codec, int index, MediaCodec.BufferInfo info)
```

I have set the target FPS as 30, so I am expecting a frame every 33 millisecs. However, the presentation time is never uniform and jumps up and down. Has anyone faced similar issue?

See the graph below. It is a graph of time between two consecutive video frames' presentation time as received (Y-Axis) in micro seconds. X-Axis is samples.

[Graph plot of video presentation time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULn1v.png)

Thank you,

Ajay

Comment: As per documentation, the presentation timestamp is derived from the presentation timestamp passed in with the corresponding input buffer. Is there a way to get the input buffer presentation timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL rendering using the Graphika sample app from Google as reference gave much more smoother presentation timestamps.

Comment: Is there any way to get a consistent presentation timestamps (33.33ms difference between frames, in case of 30fps)?

The Grafika sample from Google also does not get consistent timestamps.